# How to release H2 connection after EJB call?

Tags: jakarta-ee, h2

I have H2 v. 1.4.187.  If I use the H2 Console then I noticed there are only 2 files being created,  mv.db and/or trace.db.  I have a J2EE web application (Enity beans and EntityManager using JPA) running on Wildfly 8.2. After I run an EJB call to query the H2 db from the web application. I noticed there are two more files created, h2.db and lock.db. The h2.db has the biggest size.

So 4 files total.  After I stop Wildfly then the lock.db file disappeared. But the h2.db file is still there.

So it looks like Hibernate still opens the H2 database even after the EJB call is finished.  That's why the lock.db file is there and maybe why h2.db was created too.

Is this normal or is there a way to make it so Wildfly releases the connection after each EJB call? Therefore do not create h2.db and lock.db

Comment: Could you post the version of H2, and database URLs you are using? It looks like you use different database URLs or multiple versions of H2, because the .mv.db files are created when using version 1.4.x, and the .h2.db files are created when using version 1.3.x or 1.4.x with the setting "mv_store=false".

Comment: Here's what I have when I use the H2 console

Comment: H2 console (1.4.187): driver class: `org.h2.Driver`; JDBC URL: `jdbc:h2:file:C:/Temp/TestDB`.  Wildfly Datasource: Driver Class: `org.h2.Driver`, Connection URL: `jdbc:h2:file:C:/Temp/TestDB`. I don't have the "mv_store=false"

Comment: I added mv_store=false and now it only created the h2 db. thanks

Comment: Maybe in Wildfly you are using a different, older version of H2 (one that does not support the .mv.db files). That would explain why you saw both files at some point.